# Copy and apply Transforms

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, transforms, constraints

I have two identical cubes Cube and Cube.001. Cube.001 has a copy_transforms constraint targeting Cube. When I move and scale Cube the Cube.001 moves and scales as well but the problem the location and scale values remains 0 for loc and 1 for scale although its scale and location changed. This causes a problem to me as when I apply location and scale for Cube then Cube.001 jumps to the origin with the small scale. I want whatever I do to Cube is applied to Cube.001 so that when I apply transforms to Cube I want Cube.001 still be like a Shadow for Cube not jumps elsewhere or change it's scale.

This is Cube and Cube.001 properties as shown in the below gif, Cube.001 has a copy transforms constraint and Cube location and scale are not 0 and 1, while Cube.001 has them as 0 (loc) and 1 (scale). Once I apply location or scale for Cube, Cube.001 changes it's location and scale.

Any advice please how I can do this? I want Cube.001 to have the exact same values as Cube. I'll be doing it in python

[image]

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Applying loc / rot  and scale converts the local coordinates of the mesh to match an object with identity matrix as world_matrix. (ie zero for translation and rotation; uniform scale of 1)   The copy transform constraint is showing this as expected, as you apply loc and scale.

Comment: @batFINGER so is there a way instead of copy transforms to make one object has the exact same transforms of another object so that when I apply the transforms of both they will have the same transforms and visually be on top of each other all the time?